Remove this box from the Django Signup form
In the tutorials I've followed, I didn't see this, so I assume it's because I recently updated django to 5.1.
Now, there's this new box on the django signup view. It reads:

Password-based authentication:
Whether the user will be able to authenticate using a password or not. If disabled, they may still be able to authenticate using other
backends, such as Single Sign-On or LDAP.
Enabled
Disabled

I'd like to get rid of it as it makes the user creation process confusing for them. I'm not sure how to though.
I'm currently just using css to hide it by selecting it - but I'm sure there's a better way. I'm already using a custom signup form which does NOT have this in it:
class CustomSignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, required=True, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password1', 'password2')



https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78850636/what-is-password-based-authentication-in-django

Simply add one line in your form:
class CustomSignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    ...
    usable_password = None
    ...

